# Crypt error - 'MAC is invalid.'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

A site I am developing includes a messaging system. I am encrypting messages in the table using `Crypt::()`. A user received a message and this error was displayed:

```
exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException' with message 'MAC is invalid.' 
in /home/forge/cvahimt.org/releases/20150601155111/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php:147
```

I am encrypting the message like so:

```
// Message
        $message = Message::create(
            [
                'thread_id' => $thread->id,
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'body' => Crypt::encrypt($input['message']),
            ]
        );
```

The app key is set in the `.env` file and had not been changed, the message was sent just prior to the error occurring. The `body` column in the table is of type `TEXT`.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: solved in this thread [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070732/laravel-decryptexception-the-mac-is-invalid/47926508#47926508](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070732/laravel-decryptexception-the-mac-is-invalid/47926508#47926508)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - DecryptException: 'The MAC is invalid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070732/laravel-decryptexception-the-mac-is-invalid)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`composer dump-autoload`

`composer clear-cache`

Then, clear any seeds from your database and reseed.

Somewhere in that process, the problem should make itself apparent if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

In `app.php` you can see the following line

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString')
```

Sometimes `env` returns the `'APP_KEY'`(reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/env-not-reading-variables-sometimes) value as empty, so default value is taken as `"SomeRandomString"` while encrypting or decrypting. So, you can replace it like

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

where `'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'` exactly matches with `.env` file's `APP_KEY` value.