# Laravel - DecryptException: 'The MAC is invalid'

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel for registration I'm using encrypt algorithm for password instead of inbuilt bcrypt function in Laravel because to get password and send it to mail when password is forgot.

But decrypt it is showing a error like

```
DecryptException The MAC is invalid in Encrypter.php (line 184)
```

This , when I run this code it is working on local but server itself it is not working below i have mentioned the code , can anyone please help

```
public function forgotpassword(Request $request)
{
  $email=$request->email;
  $selectemail = User::select('email','password','name')
     ->where('email',$email)
     ->first();     

  if($selectemail)                       
  {                                 
    $password=decrypt($selectemail->password);
    $data = array( 'email' => $selectemail->email,'password' => $password , 'name' => $selectemail->name);

    Mail::send('email.resetpassword',$data,function($message) use ($email)
    {
      $message->to([$email])->subject('Forgot Password Letgo');
    });
      echo "Mail has sent successfully";
  } else {
    echo "This email is not yet registered";
  }             
}
```

Comment: Check the structure of the table in your database, looks like is too short to store a long string and it gets strip.

Comment: ok sure thanks.... but why it is working on local machine and i'm using same database only

Comment: Clear cache/cookies from the browser.

Comment: No this is for API im not using browser and also i cleared cache in laravel folder in server

Comment: You have the same APP_KEY on the local and on the server?

Comment: no i generated new APP_key on server but still facing same issue .. :(

Comment: The problem is you generated a new APP_KEY, to decrypt the old encripted data you need to have the old APP_KEY. If you stored data with the new APP_KEY you have a problem with the new data.

Comment: if when we using bcrypt .. is there any possible way to get password from database if it is hashed ??? like encrypt and decrypt ???

Comment: Nope, you need to choose one and now find a way to reset all the passwords to save them correctly on the database.

Comment: Yeah now its working when i used same API key, Thanx for ur valuable tips

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The problem is you generated a new APP_KEY, then if you try to decrypt the old encrypted data it will show the `DecryptException: The MAC is invalid`.

If you want to decrypt the old data you need to restore your old APP_KEY.

After realizing that, now, adding a new problem there, if you stored new data with another APP_KEY or another encryption method you have a problem on the data because they are mixed on the table.

In case you don't know when do you started with the new encrypt method or differentiate the new encrypted entries, the fastest solution would be reset all the passwords with the new encrypt method.

You can learn more about how Laravel encryption works on the official [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/encryption).

Comment: How do you "reset all the passwords with the new encrypt method"?

Comment: @ConnorLeech without knowing the password you simply can't do it. Probably best solution would be to force the users to change the password telling them the old one is not going to work, then save the new one with the new encrypt method.

Answer (score 10):

I copied the `APP_KEY` from the environment it was working **dev** to the **production** and the issue was solved. you may want to try it.

Comment: This could become a security issue, always prepare a mock DB data

Answer (score 4):

In case none of the above helped you, as it was in my case, well, some people mention clearing the cookies, sadly that is ambiguous to say the least.

I tried everything from the above, clear cache in laravel and the browser, hard reload and all..With no success!

SOLUTION: just CLOSE the browser entirely, and reopen it. In my case, I was using both Chrome and Opera, and they were both messing up. I had to close them BOTH, then reopen them for the MAC problem to disappear.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this, use a custom key instead. The default key is APP_KEY, but you can provide one so your decrypt is not linked with new or old APP_KEY.
I use the following code to resolve it, and it worked in different APP_KEYs.

```
function customCrypt($vWord){
    $customKey = "blabla_key_with_correct_length"; 
    $newEncrypter = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter( $customKey, Config::get( 'app.cipher' ) );
    return $newEncrypter->encrypt( $vWord );
}

function customDecrypt($vWord){
    $customKey = "blabla_key_with_correct_length";
    $newEncrypter = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter( $customKey, Config::get( 'app.cipher' ) );
    return $newEncrypter->decrypt( $vWord );
}
```

**Important for key length** : if $cipher == 'AES-128-CBC' use $length === 16, if $cipher == 'AES-256-CBC' use $length === 32). Check in `config/app.cipher` which cipher your app uses.

Comment: To add to this, for your "custom key", you don't need to know/guess the string length. You can use the `generateKey` static function of the Encrypter class like this: 
`$customKey = Encrypter::generateKey( config('app.cipher') );`

It will grab the correct cipher from your config file and return a key with the correct length.

Answer (score 2):

> App key matters in encryption and decryption. I was having 2 sub
>   domains with different projects in which I was encrypting value on sub
>   domain and 1 and trying to decrypt on sub domain 2. Issue was resolved
>   when both projects were having same appkey. Note: No projects should
>   have same appkey!!!

If you have imported DB form one environment to another, most likely you will face this error. Its recommended to have same APP_KEY as data source application in order to fix bug.

Answer (score 2):

If you run multiple project and passes one encryption key to another project, Just make sure you have made same APP_KEY to your both project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have run 2 different Laravel applications locally in the same browser, cookies can be saved in your browser. Please clear the cache and cookies before loading the 2n app.

Comment: This looks more like a comment rather than an answer. Please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having trouble, remember to restart your development server to reload your .env file ;)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to run `php artisan optimize:clear`, anything less simply did not work. For those finding this all these years later.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35425978)

Comment: @RamChander Please clarify... I believe I've answered the question and provided an answer.