# Problem when uploading to linux sever in a laravel project

Tags: php, linux, laravel, server

I try to upload a laravel project to Linux server from Windows System , then the following error appears when i try to login

```
The MAC is invalid
```

the error apears when i try to decrypt a code

```
if ($request['password'] == Crypt::decrypt(($claveDB))) {
```

I try to refresh caches, routes and so on, remake KEY_APP and the error continue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - DecryptException: 'The MAC is invalid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070732/laravel-decryptexception-the-mac-is-invalid)

Answer (score 0):

Tthe problem is because it is acted with another different encoding so you have to rebuild the passwords with that new encoding and refresh.

1. gerenare new passwords
   2.refresh all 
   php artisan route:clear 
   php artisan view:clear 
   php artisan config:clear 
   php artisan cache:clear 
   php artisan clear-compiled