# What does error 500 after laravel login mean?

Tags: laravel

I am sorry to bother everyone today with this. I have inherited a Laravel based website and came across an issue this morning. The public facing front end seems to be fine. But when I go into the admin backend I am getting an error 500. I am not so efficient with Composer and Artisan so I don't want to do to much without some guidance. I don't know what information you will need from me. I am running Laravel 5.2 on Ubunto 16.04.

I tried generating a new key and clearing caches. The staging site that is setup seems to be running fine. It is just out of date since we are updating the data weekly.

I have checked the logs. The latest entry is:

```
ErrorException: 
The MAC is invalid. 
(View: /var/www/d3multisport.com/resources/views/layouts/admin.blade.php) 
(View: /var/www/d3multisport.com/resources/views/layouts/admin.blade.php) in /var/www/d3multisport.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/BaseEncrypter.php:48 

Stack trace: #0 /var/www/d3multisport.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(44): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException), 1)
...
#72 /var/www/d3multisport.com/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
```

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.
Kevin

Comment: Can you paste the errors from the log?

Comment: A 500 error is very generic.  It's the standard http status for any server error, so it could be a number of different problems.   Seems like you need a mentor, teacher, or some professional resource to reach out to if you can't understand how to get the specific error from the logs.

Comment: The log is pretty long and I can't add it all here. What is the best way to provide it?

Comment: You should be able to find the last error at the bottom of the log and include the first few lines of the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks @AlexHarris, here is the first few lines.
Next ErrorException: The MAC is invalid. (View: /var/www/d3multisport.com/resources/views/layouts/admin.blade.php) (View: /var/www/d3multisport.com/resources/views/layouts/admin.blade.php) in /var/www/d3multisport.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/BaseEncrypter.php:48
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/d3multisport.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(44): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException), 1)

Comment: And here is the last
#72 /var/www/d3multisport.com/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - DecryptException: 'The MAC is invalid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070732/laravel-decryptexception-the-mac-is-invalid)

Comment: Can you get the old APP_KEY @KevinHester?

Comment: @ajtrichards, no I can't. It isn't in the repo and I didn't make a backup of the .env file before generating the new key.