# Laravel 5.5 No Message exception on AJAX Post Call. Line 203, Handler.php, 419 unknown status

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have been facing this issue since I started using APACHE on Windows 10 as development environment. There are absolutely many links and post discussing about same issue and none of these links address this problem.

I get "419 unknown status" of request with with bunch of other trace details:

```
"message": "",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
"line": 203,
```

When I checked with laravel.log it says,

```
local.ERROR: The MAC is invalid.
```

A. Just to get clarity, I have CSRF token in blade / html page, I have passed it in AJAX call as header:

```
headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') },
```

B. I tried with - browser cookies cleared and then, clearing artisan

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

C. I have tried to clean using composer dump-autoload and then clear-cache

```
composer clear-cache
composer dump-autoload
```

For perusal of experts, this is how my ajax call / Laravel Controller / Route code looks like:

AJAX Call:

In below code param_cust_unique_id  is passed as parameter to a function in which this ajax call is invoked.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: '/getBalanceForCustomer',
        data: { "cust_unique_id" : param_cust_unique_id },
        success: function (response) {
             console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Laravel Route:

```
Route::post('getBalanceForCustomer', 'CustomersController@getBalanceForCustomer');
```

Laravel Controller Method:

```
public function getBalanceForCustomer(Request $request) {

//Balance calculation logic, bit longer hence cutting-it short
return $balance;
}
```

I am using development environment : Visual Studio Code, MySQL Workbench, Chrome Browser.

Tech Stack is : Jquery, AngularJS, Laravel 5.5, MariaDB

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070732/laravel-decryptexception-the-mac-is-invalid

Comment: @shyammakwana.me - Nope :( it was of no help. Thanks for instant reply :)

Answer (score 3):

use this meta tag in your header

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and then ajax call:

```
let formData = $('form').serializeArray();
$.ajax({
      url: "/",
      type: "POST",
      data: {formData, "_token": $('#token').val()},
      cache: false,
      datatype: 'JSON',
      processData: false,
      success: function (response) {
           console.log(response);
         },
         error: function (response) {
           console.log(response);
         }
  });
```

Comment: So CRUX you suggest here is to add the datatype, processData and serialize data into array. Right? I will quickly try it out.

Comment: Tried : 
``` 
 url: '/getBalanceForCustomer',
 type: 'post',
 data: { dataToSend , "_token" : $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')  },
 cache: false,
 datatype: 'JSON',
 processData: false,
```

No luck :(

One more wiered thing to report : This happens only on apache, if I run artisan server I do not see this error.

Answer (score 2):

Use this meta tag in your header:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And then ajax call:

```
let formData = $('form').serializeArray();
$.ajax({
  url: "/",
  type: "POST",
  data: {formData, "_token": $('#token').val()},
  cache: false,
  datatype: 'JSON',
  processData: false,
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```