# Error "Mac is invalid" sometimes happen in Laravel project use AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8 to create an admin system to manage data for my team.
My project is deployed on a VPS use Centos7.

The problem is that, i have deployed many projects on this VPS and they work OK. But with projects used AngularJS or Axios, when i send a request to server, i get error massage "The Mac is invalid!". But these errors do not always happen, just sometime (about 50%).

I have search and follow some instructions like [Laravel - DecryptException: 'The MAC is invalid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070732/laravel-decryptexception-the-mac-is-invalid), but all not work.

I have cleared all my cache, `rm bootstrap/cache/*`, `php artisan optimize:clear`, check my `.env` file, setup new project with new `ENV_KEY`. But none of them work.

Can anyone give my some advises. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but that happend because i was using my HASH in production that was generated in development by the function encrypt()